# How to store value instead of the list that the symbol stands for in python?

Tags: python, list, loops, python-3.x

So I have similar things to this following code:

```
     for k in RANGE:
        delta = array(range(n_stack))
        while delta[2:-2].max()>0.001:
            phi_check=copy(phi0)
            R=list(range(1, half_point,1))
            shuffle(R)
            for i in R: 
                layer_energy = magnetic_energy(H[k],Ku[i],theta,Mt[i],Ms[i],\
                     Ms[i-1],phi0[i-1],J[i-1],Ms[i+1],phi0[i+1],J[i]) 
                phi_store[i] = layer_energy 
                phi_store[len(Ms)-1-i]=phi_store[i]
            phi0=phi_store
            delta = abs(phi_check - phi0) 

        phi_plot[k]=phi0
```

in which for every k I generate a phi0 and store it in the kth entry of phi_plot.But in the end I end up with every entry of phi_plot being the last phi0 that I generated. So I suppose within the loop I only store the symbol phi0 into phi_plot intead of the value of phi0. How do I solve this?

Comment: It doesn't look like `phi_plot[k]=phi0` is in your loop, I'm assuming that's a formatting error?

Comment: Please correct your formating. The while loop is messed up too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd replace:

```
phi0=phi_store
```

with:

```
phi0 = list(phi_store)
```

to make a copy of the list, instead.

Comment: I don't understand the difference, can you elaborate?

Comment: If you use `phi0 = phi_store`, `phi0` is just another name for `phi_store`. With `list` you create a (shallow) copy.